# Avoid null bytes in php serialize()

Tags: php, serialization, amazon-sqs

I am serializing php objects using php serialize(). However, it adds null bytes in the result for protected member variables. This result is then passed as a message to an Amazon SQS queue. The problem is that SQS does not support null bytes in message body. Is there any way to get rid of the null bytes. I have to make sure the result is still unserializable at the other end.

Comment: Encode the serialized objects in base64?  The size increases by a factor of 4/3 (three bytes before encoding produces ~4 bytes of base64) but that's something of a de facto standard for sending binary data over transports like SQS that are either not 8-bit-clean or that assume the payload is comprised of characters rather than arbitrary octets.  Decoding base64 on the other side should restore the identical data, by definition.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem while trying to serialize an object.

As explained in [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) comment, [`base64_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function is properly handling the NUL bytes.

On the "serializing" side you should do:

```php
base64_encode(serialize($object));
```

On the "deserializing" side:

```php
unserialize(base64_decode($object));
```

If you want to know how the [`serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function internally works, you can read
[PHP Internals Book: Serialization](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php5/classes_objects/serialization.html):

> The \0 in the above serialization string are NUL bytes. As you can see private and protected members are serialized with rather peculiar names: Private properties are prefixed with \0ClassName\0 and protected properties with \0*\0. These names are the result of name mangling, which is something we’ll cover in a later section.

Comment: Shouldn't it be unserialize(base64_decode($object)) on the deserializing side?